# general method to clearform in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I am using master page with content pages. I want to write a genral method to clear textboxes and for dropdownlist set index to 0. Please guide on this.

Comment: probably easier to do it on the client (if that suits your scenario) - `document.forms[0].reset()`

Comment: @RPM1984: That's good advice, but one thing to keep in mind is that resetting a form returns the input elements to their *default* values, which may not be an blank value for textboxes and the 0th item for drop-downs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### A Server-Side Approach

If you want to clear the TextBoxes and DropDownLists on postback, you could recurse through the page's `Controls` collection and for each control see if it's a TextBox or DropDownList. Here's such a function in C#:

```
void ClearInputs(ControlCollection ctrls)
{
    foreach (Control ctrl in ctrls)
    {
        if (ctrl is TextBox)
            ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = string.Empty;
        else if (ctrl is DropDownList)
            ((DropDownList)ctrl).ClearSelection();

        ClearInputs(ctrl.Controls);
    }
}
```

To use this you'd call `ClearInputs` passing in the control collection you want to search. To clear out *all* TextBoxes and DropDownLists on the page you'd use:

```
ClearInputs(Page.Controls);
```

#### A Client-Side Approach

An alternative tactic would be to use a client-side approach. Namely, use JavaScript to recurse through the DOM and clear/reset the textboxes and drop-downs on this page. The following JavaScript uses the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/) to simplify things:

```
function clearElements() {
    $("input[type=text]").val('');
    $("select").attr('selectedIndex', 0); 
}
```

In a nutshell, it sets the `value` of all `<input type="text" ... />` elements on the page to an empty string and sets the `selectedIndex` attribute of all `<select>` elements on the page to 0. I've created a script on JSFiddle.net to let you try out the script: http://jsfiddle.net/xs6G9/

#### For More Information

I wrote a blog entry on this topic with more information and discussion. See: [Resetting Form Field Values in an ASP.NET WebForm](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2010/12/23/resetting-form-field-values-in-an-asp-net-webform.aspx).

Happy Programming!

Comment: Scott one thing further please. I am also filling some textboxes in form with ajax which are not cleared by this funtions. Is this because in viewstate they are already empty ?

Comment: @haansi: If you are loading values into the TextBox *after* the postback then what's happening is that the TextBox is being cleared on postback by `ClearInputs`, but then it has a value added on the client side. Let me update my answer to include a client-side option, as well.

Comment: if I called ClearInputs after getting data with Ajax (which will be once) should it not clear the form ? If it is clearing then from where controls are getting values again. Please guide. Thanks

Comment: @haansi: Maybe the way to go is with client-side code... see my amended answer.

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="reset">` is a simple solution client side.

Comment: The problem is that reset returns the input fields to the initial state, which might not be an empty textbox and initially selected listitem, especially if there was a postback on the page (like a DropDownList with AutoPostBack enabled). See http://bit.ly/hS6zm1 for more on this topic...