# Is there a way to reset all data in an asp:Wizard on Back button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, navigation, reset, web-controls

I have an `<asp:Wizard>` tag with a few pages, each Step page with a Back button allowing to go back to the previous wizard page.

This causes me problem because of this flow:

- 1 - user is in page 3 for example;
- 2 - he fills some data before realizing he made a bad selection in page 2;
- 3 - he click Back and goes to page 2;
- 4 - fixes his chose (the data in page 3 won't be of any use now)
- 5 - he clicks Next and goes to page 3. HERE IS MY PROBLEM. **The data was persisted and when in page 3 the user sees his old data. How do I clear this?**

I'm new to ASP.NET WebForms. Please help, I'm stuck with this and don't even know how to approach it. But I assume I don't need to reset all fields by hand!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<asp:WizardStep ID="Step3" runat="server" Title="Step 3" EnableViewState="False">
```

**UPDATE**

There are some easy ways to reset all fields in your WebForm.

1. HTML reset button:

   input type="reset" value="Reset Form!" />
2. Javascript:

   ```
   function resetforms() {document.forms[0].reset(); return false;}
   ```
3. Calling the same javascript from the codebehind:

   ```
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "MyScript", "document.forms[0].reset();return false;", true);
   ```

Unfortunately those three won't work in case with asp:Wizard because they all reset controls to values persisted in ViewState after PostBack.

So the most appropriate option I've found is to use a handcoded recursive method which will be called from the Wizard's PreviousButtonClick event handler:

```
    private void ClearInputs(ControlCollection ctrls)
    {
        foreach (Control ctrl in ctrls)
        {
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
                ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = string.Empty;
            else if (ctrl is DropDownList)
                ((DropDownList)ctrl).ClearSelection();
            else if (ctrl is CheckBox)
                ((CheckBox)ctrl).Checked = false;

            ClearInputs(ctrl.Controls);
        }
    }

    protected void YourWizardName_PreviousButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        ClearInputs(YourWizardName.WizardSteps[e.CurrentStepIndex].Controls);
    }
```

The method above will reset all textboxes, dropdownlists and checkboxes of the current WizardStep if the user clicks on the Previous button (before forwarding the user to the previous step). So if you need to clear any other controls you'll have to add appropriate code into the ClearInputs() method.

The code is adapted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4504999/general-method-to-clearform-in-asp-net) post. There you can find more details on how the method works and also the way to solve the same task using jQuery.

Comment: As I understand, the ViewState contains the data from my form controls. If I do this and I navigate to page 4, 5... Finish page, will I have all my data at the end or will I be missing the data from step 3?

Comment: You're right, that's a poor solution if step 3 is not the final one.